While requesting a Vault token using the Kubernetes auth: error calling Vault server: context deadline exceeded
Once applied the issuer, it seems ok :
root@k8s-eu-1-control-plane-node-1:~# kubectl describe issuers vault-issuer
Name:         vault-issuer
Namespace:    default
Labels:       <none>
Annotations:  <none>
API Version:  cert-manager.io/v1
Kind:         Issuer
Metadata:
  Creation Timestamp:  2024-09-13T13:05:49Z
  Generation:          1
  Resource Version:    4491557
  UID:                 78a71f66-e92a-446d-b74b-a62fe5ea53d1
Spec:
  Vault:
    Auth:
      Kubernetes:
        Mount Path:  /v1/auth/kubernetes
        Role:        issuer
        Secret Ref:
          Key:   token
          Name:  issuer-token-abcde
    Path:        pki_int/sign/nats
    Server:      http://bb.bbb.bbb.bb:8200
Events:          <none>

But, just after few seconds, I get this error message :
root@k8s-eu-1-control-plane-node-1:~# kubectl describe issuers vault-issuer
Name:         vault-issuer
Namespace:    default
Labels:       <none>
Annotations:  <none>
API Version:  cert-manager.io/v1
Kind:         Issuer
Metadata:
  Creation Timestamp:  2024-09-13T13:05:49Z
  Generation:          1
  Resource Version:    4491893
  UID:                 78a71f66-e92a-446d-b74b-a62fe5ea53d1
Spec:
  Vault:
    Auth:
      Kubernetes:
        Mount Path:  /v1/auth/kubernetes
        Role:        issuer
        Secret Ref:
          Key:   token
          Name:  issuer-token-abcde
    Path:        pki_int/sign/nats
    Server:      http://bb.bbb.bbb.bb:8200
Status:
  Conditions:
    Last Transition Time:  2024-09-13T13:06:49Z
    Message:               Failed to initialize Vault client: while requesting a Vault token using the Kubernetes auth: error calling Vault server: context deadline exceeded
    Observed Generation:   1
    Reason:                VaultError
    Status:                False
    Type:                  Ready
Events:
  Type     Reason         Age   From                  Message
  ----     ------         ----  ----                  -------
  Warning  ErrInitIssuer  38s   cert-manager-issuers  Error initializing issuer: while requesting a Vault token using the Kubernetes auth: error calling Vault server: context deadline exceeded

When deploying Vault I applied the following configuration  Vault-Config/overrides.yaml  :
global:
   enabled: true
   tlsDisable: false
injector:
   enabled: true
server:
   extraEnvironmentVars:
      VAULT_CACERT: /vault/userconfig/vault-ha-tls/vault.ca
      VAULT_TLSCERT: /vault/userconfig/vault-ha-tls/vault.crt
      VAULT_TLSKEY: /vault/userconfig/vault-ha-tls/vault.key
      VAULT_CLIENT_TIMEOUT: "10000000000s"
   dataStorage:
       enabled: true
   volumes:
      - name: userconfig-vault-ha-tls
        secret:
         defaultMode: 420
         secretName: vault-ha-tls
   volumeMounts:
      - mountPath: /vault/userconfig/vault-ha-tls
        name: userconfig-vault-ha-tls
        readOnly: true
   standalone:
      enabled: false
   affinity: ""
   readinessProbe:
     enabled: true
     path: "/v1/sys/health?standbyok=true&sealedcode=204&uninitcode=204"
   ha:
      enabled: true
      replicas: 3
      raft:
         enabled: true
         setNodeId: true
         config: |
            cluster_name = "vault-integrated-storage"
            ui = true
            listener "tcp" {
               tls_disable = 0
               address = "[::]:8200"
               #address = "127.0.0.1:8200"
               cluster_address = "[::]:8201"
               #cluster_address = "127.0.0.1:8201"
               tls_cert_file = "/vault/userconfig/vault-ha-tls/vault.crt"
               tls_key_file  = "/vault/userconfig/vault-ha-tls/vault.key"
               tls_client_ca_file = "/vault/userconfig/vault-ha-tls/vault.ca"
            }

            # https://developer.hashicorp.com/vault/tutorials/kubernetes/kubernetes-raft-deployment-guide#vault-storage-configuration

            storage "raft" {
               path = "/vault/data"

               retry_join {
                 leader_api_addr = "https://vault-0.vault-internal:8200"
                 leader_ca_cert_file = "/vault/userconfig/tls-ca/ca.crt"
                 leader_client_cert_file = "/vault/userconfig/tls-server/tls.crt"
                 leader_client_key_file = "/vault/userconfig/tls-server/tls.key"
               }

               retry_join {
                 leader_api_addr = "https://vault-1.vault-internal:8200"
                 leader_ca_cert_file = "/vault/userconfig/tls-ca/ca.crt"
                 leader_client_cert_file = "/vault/userconfig/tls-server/tls.crt"
                 leader_client_key_file = "/vault/userconfig/tls-server/tls.key"
               }

               retry_join {
                 leader_api_addr = "https://vault-2.vault-internal:8200"
                 leader_ca_cert_file = "/vault/userconfig/tls-ca/ca.crt"
                 leader_client_cert_file = "/vault/userconfig/tls-server/tls.crt"
                 leader_client_key_file = "/vault/userconfig/tls-server/tls.key"
               }

               retry_join {
                 leader_api_addr = "https://vault-3.vault-internal:8200"
                 leader_ca_cert_file = "/vault/userconfig/tls-ca/ca.crt"
                 leader_client_cert_file = "/vault/userconfig/tls-server/tls.crt"
                 leader_client_key_file = "/vault/userconfig/tls-server/tls.key"
               }

               retry_join {
                 leader_api_addr = "https://vault-4.vault-internal:8200"
                 leader_ca_cert_file = "/vault/userconfig/tls-ca/ca.crt"
                 leader_client_cert_file = "/vault/userconfig/tls-server/tls.crt"
                 leader_client_key_file = "/vault/userconfig/tls-server/tls.key"
               }

               autopilot {
                 server_stabilization_time = "10s"
                 last_contact_threshold = "10s"
                 min_quorum = 5
                 cleanup_dead_servers = false
                 dead_server_last_contact_threshold = "10m"
                 max_trailing_logs = 1000
                 disable_upgrade_migration = false
               }


            }
            disable_mlock = true
            service_registration "kubernetes" {}

What's going on? How to prevent this error to occur?
